# Log-space probability of a log-space probability not occurring

Tags: probability, logarithms

Normally the probability of some probability $p$ not occurring would be $1-p$. However, I'm working with very small probabilities and therefore must work with $p$ in $\log$ space (Ie. I'm working with values of $\log(p)$ rather than $p$, otherwise I would receive an [underflow error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow)).

How do I find the value of `log(1-p)` without converting `p` back to base 10? (Ie. without first calculating `10^log(p)`).

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is very small then $\log (1 - p) \simeq -p$ will also be very small, so you'll get underflow. How are you going to avoid that underflow?

Comment: Ahh... I think you're right, the underflow is unavoidable in this case. Thanks for your response!